# Differences and advantages of window managers in xcb (libxcb) over ones in libx11?

Tags: window-manager, window-management

What are the differences and advantages of window managers written in xcb (libxcb) over ones written in libx11?

In the field of tilling and new/moderm window managers I often come across these kind of WMs. I want to know what would tip the scale in favor of one of them in window managers.

Answer (score 3):

None that would be caused directly by using either `libx11` or `libxcb` based WMs. It's as if you asked whether there are some advantages of using applications `libncurses` over `libslang` (TUI libraries). The difference is almost purely on the source code level - "almost" because there might be some slight differences in performance and/or binary size, although with today's systems you are unlikely to notice those.

Unless you want to actively develop the WM, it really doesn't matter. If you *do* want to help with development, then it might be more important to choose by the language it is written in (and it's not just C vs. C++ decision - e.g. `xmonad` is written in Haskell, `qtile` in Python) and how nice the codebase is.